# Remove dynamically created div in modal without closing it on data submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a dynamically created div inside a modal
[image]

I would like to remove the details entered on the modal after data has been submitted without closing the modal on the click of a button.

Here is my code

```
$('.claimadditem').click(function(){
 var divdetails= $('<div style="padding: 5px;" class="form-group dts" id="detailsentry"><div class="col-sm-4"><input class="form-control" name="servicedate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date"></div><div class="col-sm-4"><input name="unitsofservice[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Units" type="text"></div></div>');
 var sopra=$('.claimadditem');

$(sopra).after(divdetails)
})

});
```

Comment: Did you tried $('.dts').find('input:text').val('');?

Comment: I have tried but it didn't work

Comment: What is the exactly issue? Form data are not being cleared or popup are being close on button click? Please post more information so we can help.

Comment: Form data is not clearing when data is submited

Comment: I have added logic in answer to clear data. I hope you will get an idea!

Comment: do you want to remove the div? or you want to remove the value of your input text?

Comment: I want to remove the div with all its data

Answer (score 1):

Look into below logic so you can get more idea!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.claimadditem').click(function() {
    var divdetails = $('<div style="padding: 5px;" class="form-group dts" id="detailsentry"><div class="col-sm-6"><input class="form-control" name="servicedate" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" type="date"></div><div class="col-sm-6"><input name="unitsofservice[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Units" type="text"></div></div>');
    var sopra = $('.claimadditem');

    $(sopra).after(divdetails)

    cleardata();
  });
});

function cleardata() {
  var formControls = $('.dts').find('input');
  formControls.each(function() {
    $(this).val('');
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Save & Create New" class="claimadditem" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery remove function

```
jQuery(".YourClass").remove();
```

Comment: I have a function to clear data and my class name is dts 
function cleardata(){
} KIndly give more info